# Set delegate to class type not to instance in Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

In Objective-C it was possible to set a class as a delegate (not an instance of a class but a pure class). Is it possible in Swift?

Comment: How would you do that in Objective-C?

Comment: av.delegate = [MyClass class]

Comment: I did not downvote. I was not clear about a question and wanted to clarify.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Yes it is**

Declare a `delegate` variable to be a class type, not instance type.
I also make it optional, but we could also make it non-optional and pass it in the init method.

```
var delegate : Int.Type?
```

**Code Example**

```
class A {
  static func sayHello() {
    println("Hello")
  }
}

class B {
  var num = 10
  var delegate : A.Type?
  func hi() {
    delegate?.sayHello()
  }
}

var b = B()
b.delegate = A.self
b.hi()
```

Comment: Does it mean for `UIAlertView` it will not work? delegate is not class type I guess.

Comment: You want to assign a class to a delete of a UIAlertView ?

Comment: Here is the UIAlertView init method -
 `init(title: String?, message: String?, delegate: AnyObject?, cancelButtonTitle: String?)` the delegate is `AnyObject` it means it has to be an instance not a class. If it would accept a class then it would be `AnyClass` type.
I hope I've answered your question

Comment: Can you show the exact code? maybe it would be easier to help.